# How to run multiple test case on multiple test suite parallely in robot framework | Python

Tags: python, robotframework

I have developed a tool for automated web testing of 3 urls using robot framework python. I just wanted to execute all the test suites parallelly, along with test cases it should also run parallelly
for example

```
URL1 - TestCase1 , TestCase2

URL2 - TestCase1 , TestCase2

URL3 - TestCase1, TestCase2
```

Here I should run all this TestSuites ( URL1, URL2, URL3) parallelly , and each testcase in a test suite should run parallelly.

Is there any way I can do that? Currently I did something like this, which allows me to run all the testcases parallelly , but it executes all together (Test Suites ). I want each of the Test Suite to produce report separately.

```
os.system(
            'cmd /c "pabot --testlevelsplit  --processes  10'
            ' --outputdir   C:/filemanager/'+log_time+'/'
            '    C:/Users/abc/*.robot"'
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I follow, Ruli.  If you want your own brand of parallelism, then you do not even need pabot.  Just spawn simultaneous process shells.  Background them as UNIX jobs using &,  `jobs` and `fg` for bash built-in job control.

Seems as though you already know how to use `pabot` since you give it in your example, but perhaps your solution is NOT using it.

I like the way `pabot` retains the integrity of a given Test Suite, i.e. does not attempt parallel execution of tests within a Test Suite, by design.

Since the parallelism you seek is to have URL1, URL2 and URL3 run at the same time and produce, each on their own, Robot reports - then run them separately!

Comment: Who is Rudi? :)

Comment: Rudi is Ruli's parallel self.

Comment: Hi @SteveRawlins , but in robot i cannot use testsplit , testsplit is used to run testcases parallely

Comment: Is there any way i can use MultiThreading in Python to solve this problem @SteveRawlins

Comment: Mind that Ruli is just someone who edited the question.